# How can I load the pretrained GoogleNews model using word2vec in R?

Tags: r, word2vec, pre-trained-model

I am trying to use the pre-trained word2vec model from GoogleNews in R: https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/
I have downloaded the GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz file from the provided link and unzipped the file afterwards. Next, I tried to load the model into R using word2vec:

```
library(word2vec)
google_emb <- read.word2vec(file = "C:\\Users\\my_name\\Documents\\Model\\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", normalize = TRUE)
```

However, this returns:
**Error: fileMapper: file C:\Users\my_name\Documents\Model\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin is empty, nothing to read**

I have:

- confirmed that I am using the correct (absolute) path
- checked that the file is not empty both manually and through R. The file has a size of 3.4gb.
  `file.info("C:\\Users\\my_name\\Documents\\Model\\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin")`
  returns a size of 3644258522
- checked whether I have all file permissions and started Rstudio as admin
- updated both RStudio and word2vec to their most recent versions
- ran the corresponding code using Python where the GoogleNews model is read correctly:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('C:\\Users\\my_name\\Documents\\Model\\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

I am at a loss what may be causing the issue in R, any help is much appreciated!